# Oracle - how to find deleted views?

Tags: oracle

How can I find in oracle the name of all the deleted views?
just the name, i don't need to restore it.

thanks

Comment: couldn't find it there for some reason..maybe it was deleted from there as well.. is there another option?

Comment: Maybe someone purge the recyclebin. Or the recyclebin is not enabled in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the these links 
[link1](http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2.php)
[link2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#i1007854) which help to identify objects activity in the schema

Comment: but i thought auditing will help me from now on, not retro, isn't it?

Comment: in my view auditing will be help full as it has a column which determines the thing happened to that objects

Comment: you know what? you're right, it is very helpful. i used this link: http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2.php and i'm starting to query the audited objects to find what i'm looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM RECYCLEBIN;
```

More information about this problem you find in [documenatiation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#ADMIN01511) how using Flashback

Comment: couldn't find it there for some reason..maybe it was deleted from there as well.. is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will should give you owner and name of views dropped in the last 15 minutes. What you have to keep in mind is it will work only if necessary undo segments are in the UNDO_TABLESPACE so if you try for 15 minutes it will probably work unless your undo_tablespace is tiny, but for 24 Hours it will probably not work. And for it to work i think you have to connect with the user sys.

```
SELECT u.NAME as owner, o.name view_name 
from  sys.OBJ$ as of timestamp(systimestamp-(interval '15' Minute)) o, sys.user$ u
where u.USER# = o.owner# 
and o.obj# in (
select obj# from sys.view$ as of timestamp(systimestamp-(interval '15' Minute))
minus
select obj# from sys.view$)
```